# More than 15 columns in Novacode DocX Table

Tags: c#, docx, novacode-docx

Is there a way to create a word table with more than 15 columns using Novacode DocX?

If I create a new table with greater than 14 columns, the table doesn't appear.  I can get around this by doing something like this:

```
int addCols = Math.Min(data.colCount, 14);
Table docTable = doc.InsertTable(data.rowCount, addCols);
```

And then later this:

```
docTable.InsertColumn();
```

However, if I try to do this more than once to create a table with 16 or more columns, I have the same issue where the table doesn't appear.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Are your `Tables` having a common number of columns? or are they changing often?

Comment: They are changing often - they may have anything from 5 to 17 columns

Comment: You can use code below with an if statement `addCols > 14` just to create table. Then have 3 different tables on other document. template2.Tables[0] have 15, template2.Tables[1] have 16, and template2.Tables[2] have 17 columns. Then use the other way you are doing it on anything less than 15

Answer (score 1):

Here is my way around this. This might not work if you need many different tables with random large numbers of columns because it would take a lot of work.

```
using (DocX template = DocX.Load("template.docx"))
{
     Novacode.Table tempTable;
     using (DocX template2 = DocX.Load("template2.docx"))
     {
          tempTable = template2.Tables[0];
     }
     Novacode.Table t1 = doc.InsertTable(tempTable);
     t1.InsertRow();
     t1.InsertRow();
     template.Save();
}
```

This is a possible solution. `template` is the `DocX` you are inserting a `Table` into. `template2` contains pre-made `Tables` that are 1 row and have as many columns as you would like. So `template2.Table[0]` would be a `Table` size (1,15). You can then add more `Tables` to `template2` (outside of code by creating them within the document in Microsoft Word) growing larger: `template2.Table[1]` would be a `Table` size (1,16). The only issue is if you have a lot of different number of column `Tables` that you need to work with. `Novacode-dox` is not a very good library for building things from scratch.

Hope this might be a work around for you.

Answer (score 1):

There is something like a bug in the library. When you create a table with many columns it becomes unusable. Reason is, that each column is created with its initial width. When you create table (independatly of the used method: InsertTable, AddTable, InsertTableBeforeSelf etc.) with many columns and the sum of their widths exceeds the document width - the table becomes unusable.

I solved this problem by adding columns in cycle and decreasing their width.
My code is similar to this:

```
private void CreateSampleTable(DocX document)
{
    int rowsCount = 10;
    int columnsCount = 20;
    int columnWidth = 30;

    Table sampleTable = document.AddTable(rowsCount, 1);
    foreach (Row row in sampleTable.Rows)
    {
        row.Cells[0].Width = columnWidth;
    }

    for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex < columnsCount; colIndex++)
    {
        sampleTable.InsertColumn(colIndex);
        foreach (Row row in sampleTable.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[colIndex].Width = columnWidth;
        }
    }

    Paragraph par = document.InsertParagraph();
    par.InsertTableBeforeSelf(sampleTable);
}
```